# Got a little epoxy down a bathtub drain

Tags: drain, epoxy

I got a little bit of epoxy down my bathtub drain. Will it cause a problem? Hasn’t cured yet. How do I remove it prior to curing?

Comment: Which "bathroom drain?" Sink, tub, floor, toilet, other?

Comment: How little?  A couple of drops a lot better than a small tube or two.

Comment: Tub. Not certain. I was able to get the part I saw out. That was about a tablespoon

Comment: Tablespoon is not small amount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it hasn't cured yet, read the directions on how to clean up excess epoxy. If it has cured, then try to chip it out with a small chisel but be careful not to damage piping if PVC. If it's just a small amoumt and smooth in the drain, it shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: I wiped out the part I saw, about a tablespoon. It’s the bathtub so I can’t chip at it.

Comment: @user164539  Isopropyl alcohol will thin out the epoxy if it hasn't dried so dump some down the drain. It won't hurt the pipes.  Also run water down the drain. This epoxy  doesn't like water. If you removed a tablespoon, that's good.

Comment: @user164539   It dries to touch in an hour and needs three days before exposure to water so hopefully it won't harden and will wash away

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Epoxy once hardened can not be removed.

How much of a problem will it be, who knows.

However if the pipe was very wet when the accident happened you might be lucky and it will form a clump and not stick to the pipe.

If clump it might be washed down the drain and not get stuck in it.

To investigate the damage get a snake camera.

If it is stuck to the walls, you will have reduced drain flow.

Comment: It’s not dry. It’s still wet. I got everything I could see out. Can I pour acetone down the drain?

Comment: @user164539, I would not do that. It might attack the PVC pipe

Comment: Okay. Should I run the water so that  it gets diluted before curing?

Comment: @user164539 did you disclose what epoxy was it ?

Comment: It’s Rust-OLeum tub and tile refinishing kit.

Comment: @user164539 great, now read the instructions

Comment: Thanks for your help previously . Fyi , I read the instructions and it doesn’t mention it. Thanks.